# how to transfer data div to input

Tags: html, input

i want to transfer data from div to hidden input

```
<div id="timing"><table>...i need date from here...</table></div>
```

my solve ,but it doesnt work:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#textarea').keyup(function() {
         $('#dateD').html($('#div.timing').html());
     });
 });
</script>

<input type="hidden" id="dateD" value="" name="time1" >
```

Comment: Where is your element with id `textarea`? Where is your element with id `dateD`?  Where is your element with id `div` and class `timing`?

Comment: 1)i'm sorry i dont have element texterea.what i need to  specify?

Comment: 2) id="dateD" from input  3) <div id="timing"> i need take all inside it

Comment: What your code is saying is that you have an element with an id of textarea (meaning something like `<div id=textarea></div>` and when someone types in that element you want to get the html from some other element in your page that has an id of div and a class of timing and put the contents in another element with id of dateD.

Comment: aa ok. and its not right?:                                
     $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#timing').keyup(function() {
       $('#dateD').val($('#timing').text());
   });
});

Answer (score 1):

Here, change from html(...) to val(...) and html() to text() :)

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#textarea').keyup(function() {
       $('#dateD').val($('#div.timing').text());
   });
});
</script>

<input type="hidden" id="dateD" value="" name="time1">
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('#timing').text()` allows you to do this.